# How to avoid creating multiple functions for same command but different input?

Tags: python

I have an executable that I run over and over again called 'a' that can be called with many parameters. I am thinking about defining different functions for it and then calling it in main like below. The output from one command becomes input to the next one. Is programmatically right? I know it will work though.

```
def d(x, z):    

    c =['a', 'x', '-m', '1', '-d', '-g', '5', '-o', 'z1']

    return c

def e(x, z1):    

    b =['a', 'x','-m', '1', '-d', '-p', 'in', '-o', 'z2']

    return b

def f(x, z2):    

    k =['a', 'x','-m', 'side', '-d', '-y','-p', 'in', '-o', 'z3']

    return k

def main():

    run1 = d('in.txt', 'w1')
    j = ' '.join(run1)
    result1 = subprocess.call(j)

    run2 = e('w1', 'w2')
    m = ' '.join(run2)
    result2 = subprocess.call(m)

    run3 = f('w2', 'w3')
    m = ' '.join(run3)
    result3 = subprocess.call(m)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you have some missing quotation marks (near `in`). Also, what is the purpose of the arguments `x` `z1` and `z2` if they are not used in `e` and `f` functions?
Also, you don't need to define `b` and `k` - you can directly return your list (e.g. `return ['a', '-m' ]` etc

Comment: -o generates output as z1, z2 and x is a file

Comment: but you are not using them inside the functions. Are you trying to construct a full command line with arguments? i.e. comment -e file.txt -b output.out -c square etc?

Comment: sorry the x should be after a

Comment: All the elements of your lists are quoted: they are strings. You never use the values given in input in your functions.

Comment: i use join to get the full command and then run it in main using subprocess

Comment: Yes, but that does not change the fact that your `''.join(run1)` will be `'ax-m1-d-g5-oz1'` whatever arguments you give in input to `d()`.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. It should be a space join

Comment: Functions `d()`, `e()`, and `f()` don't use the arguments they're passed — so your question doesn't make much sense to me as it now stands.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so assuming I now understand what you want, you want to remove the passed arguments (that are already strings) from the quotation marks:

You also need a space between the elements,

I also simplified some of your code a bit

```
def d(x, z):    
    return ' '.join(['a', x , '-m', '1', '-d', '-g', '5', '-o', z])

def e(x, z):    
    return ' '.join(['a', x, '-m', '1', '-d', '-p', 'in', '-o', z])

def f(x, z):    
    return ' '.join(['a', x, '-m', 'side', '-d', '-y','-p', 'in', '-o', z])


def main():

    result1 = subprocess.call(d('in.txt', 'w1'))

    result2 = subprocess.call(e('w1', 'w2'))

    result3 = subprocess.call(f('w2', 'w3'))    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit: I don't think it is much better, but if you have lots of options, maybe you can work from that and improve it (or someone else can suggest something better):

```
def generate_line(x, z, flag):    
    flags = {'d':('1',('-g','5')), 'e':('1',('-p','in')),'f':('side',('-y','p','in'))}
    aa,bb = flags[flag]
    l = ' '.join(['a', x , '-m', aa, '-d', *bb, '-o', z])
    return l

def main():
    result1 = print(generate_line('in.txt', 'w1','d'))
    result2 = print(generate_line('w1', 'w2','e'))
    result3 = print(generate_line('w2', 'w3','f'))
```

Comment: Thank you, so no way to avoid having multiple functions for the commands I guess. Like a class or something different by taking out command arguments that are same across the board

Comment: ooooh, so that's what you mean? Let me think and edit my answer

Comment: I suggest format strings... eg `"a {x} -m 1 -d -g 5 -o {z}"`.format(x=x, z=z)

Comment: I added some suggestion, it is not great though. Also, you probably want to modify the code as @kevinsa5 suggested (I didn't do it for the sake of simplicity)

Comment: oh, that's much shorter. I need to study what's going on there. Thank you

Comment: in short, you pass a flag of what 'type' of output you want. Then you have a dictionary of flags, and using the flag, you extract from the dictionary `aa` and `bb` (since all other arguments are identical in all 3 methods). Since `bb` has multiple elements, you pass it with an `*` to pass it as elements rather than a single object. I think that should cover and you can modify as needed easily from there (also you can mark the question as answered if you are satisfied with this solution)

Comment: I tried to vote but I can't. Says I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Doesn't matter :) I'm glad it helped

Comment: Thank you for not avoiding my questions cos of reputation. I will vote once I get enough rep. I will come back to vote